# Compiling a portable Perl and including a CPAN module

Tags: perl, compilation, perl-module, portable-executable

I am trying to compile a portable version of perl containing a CPAN module, specifically the YAML module. I intend to be able copy this portable version into my home directory on numerous Redhat Linux machines, add it to my $PATH and use this version instead of the default perl version to run some tests.

I have already managed to compile a portable version of perl and got it working on different machines. However, when I compile the YAML module and install it, it works locally but then fails when I copy it to other machines.

Here's my compilation steps locally for the YAML module

```
perl Makefile.pl
make test
make install
```

Which installs the YAML module locally and also works locally when I use the YAML module in a script.

This is the error once I copy perl to another machine and try to use the YAML module...

```
Can't locate loadable object for module YAML::XS::LibYAML in @INC
```

even though lib/site_perl/5.10.1/x86_64-linux/YAML/LibYAML.pm exists in my local copy.

Is what I'm attempting to do possible?
If so, where am I going wrong?

Comment: The error message is not complaining about YAML::LibYAML, it's complaining about YAML::XS::LibYAML.

Comment: And not about YAML::XS::LibYAML, but C part of it - LibYAML.so (or something like that).

Comment: I'm sure the YAML-LibYAML module contains YAML::XS. I think you're right though Alexandr, somehow the C part of the module is not portable once it's compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you should explore [PAR](http://par.perl.org/wiki/Main_Page) with which you can create an archive of your module dependencies and ship it alongside your application.

Comment: I think PAR would help me achieve what I'm after, thanks. However, I still don't understand why my earlier method faild.

Comment: Jira, I finally got round to exploring PAR and it is indeed what I require. Works brilliantly, thank's again.